# When editing a contact form 7 form the edit page is blank

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have 6 contact forms all working 100% fine and I can edit them and so forth. The moment I try to open this form(Called 'Job Form') Wordpress gives me a blank edit page. I switched on WP debug and PHP errors and all I got was a white pages with no errors when trying to edit the form. My console log also presents no errors.

Is there anything else I can try to fix this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Using [Contact form 7 Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just Resolved this by switching themes. The issue seems to be with the Elegan Themes:  Divi theme